# Can't get GetListItems working in Internet Explorer 7

Tags: spservices, internet-explorer, browser-compatibility

In the below code, I'm using SPServices library to get a list item's author's name.

```
$().SPServices({
                operation: "GetListItems",
                async: false,
                listName: "MyList",
                CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
                CAMLQuery: "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Integer'>" + id + "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
                completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
                    $(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").each(function() {
                        alert($(this).attr("ows_Author")));
                    });
                }
            });
```

Only in IE7 and IE8, it returns null. *$(xData.responseXML).find("[nodeName='z:row']").length* equals to 0. In other browsers it works fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out IE7 recognizes my site's URL different than the other browsers. Re-creating the site solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you posted this on the SPServices forum on Codeplex ([spservices.codeplex.com](http://spservices.codeplex.com))?

I've never tried to use the Properties='True' attribute for ViewFields with SPServices. Do you get the same behavior if you remove that? The rest of your script looks correct.